# The relation of domain and image of a function and its inverse

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse

> *Theorem*: Let both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ be functions. $\newcommand{\dom}{\operatorname{dom}}\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$ Then $\dom(f) = \im(f^{-1})$ and $\dom(f^{-1}) = \im(f)$.

Let $f: X \to Y$ be an injective function. It might not be true that $f^{-1}: Y \to X$ since it's not necessarily true that $f(X) = Y$. So for $f^{-1}$ to exist $f$ must also be surjective, right? So, suppose that $f$ is a non-surjective function. Does it contradict the theorem above since according to it $f$ is any function? I know that there's a hole somewhere in my reasoning, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: $f^{-1}(y)$ can only be defined for those $y\in Y$ which get "hit" by $f$, i.e., for $\operatorname{im}(f)$. Remember, the image $\operatorname{im}(f) = \{y\in Y : y=f(x) \textrm{ for some }x\in X\}$. So it doesn't matter if $f$ is surjective -- the image of $f$ "throws away" all the other points of $Y$ that prevent $f$ from being surjective.

Comment: Does that mean the author forgot to specify that $f$ and $f^-1$ are both bijective in the theorem above?

Comment: @Shark: as MPW said, $f^{-1}$ is defined only from the image of $f.$ similarly, $f^{-1}$ is also defined only when $f$ is injective. so $f$ is bijective up to its image. it need not have to be a bijection between $X$ and $Y$ (as per your notation).

Comment: @ everyone, so the theorem is not true if we replace image with codomain like I have done. I see. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of TeX like $Theorem$, use Markdown for italics: *Theorem*. There is also **bold**. See [formatting guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)